# Ad manager not display ads on certain domains

Tags: angular, google-ad-manager

I've always had ads displaying on my site (last change was 5 months ago),but in this week the ads just stopped displaying on production, because on localhost was fine.

We are using Angular aplications hosted on aws and the ads are manage with Google Ad Manager

I thought that could be some kinda of firewall, so we disabled everything for testing purposes, nothing happened. We even tried to move the intire deploy to Vercel, but nothing happened.

In this changes, we noticed ads worked in every domain, not only localhost, except our main domain of course.

None configuration was changed at Google ad manager.

I tried to make contact with Google, but every time it gives me error and none response on their forum.

If anyone could help me with this, I would appreciate

**Edit 1**

- Ad example on google console

[image]

- Example request secure pubs ad. I noticed in this request the data is almost all null

[image]

Comment: could you run googletag.openconsole() on your webpage console and share the messages ?

Comment: I added an edit

Comment: looks like you do not call the display function anymore. See here https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference?hl=en#googletag.display

Comment: Well, I don't know about this, because the ads are working on localhost. Can this be a configuration on AWS?